# Key typed event: getKeyCode() returns 0

Tags: java-8, keylistener, keyevent, keycode

I want to write this listener to the "keyTyped" event.(Not keyPressed event)
Here's my code.

```
 private void jTableKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                               
    if (evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
         int y = evt.getKeyCode();
         System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

The problem is that for any key is being typed, the results is 0.
Why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `key typed events`: the `getKeyCode` method always returns
>   `VK_UNDEFINED` which returns `0`.

If you want to know when any key is pressed or released, you need to implement `keyPressed()` or `keyReleased()`

> `key pressed` and `key released` events, the `getKeyCode` method
>   returns the `event's keyCode`

See [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)